# How to get each tab page with different header style and content in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-router-v4

I tried tab navigation but header is same of main root page , how to get different header for each tab section please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set navigation options for each screen component you specified in your tabnavigator. For example you have a HomeView:

```
class HomeView extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Manage Contacts',
  }
  render() ...
}
```

check out the docs which navigationOptions you can set: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigationoptions-used-by-stacknavigator

Comment: Thank you for reply but for separate screen this will work but i just created bottom tab , in which there is a main screen and inside that main screen  i put one and second screen , so these two screen is inside main screen so , navigatioOptions of this main screen is applicable and same style is showing in each page because of this parent page

Comment: I mean you set navigationOptions for any screen separately. I don't understand your issue

Answer (score 0):

For parent class, you need to remove the header:-

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}
```

For child classes, you can use the default header properties or you can even user the custom header class as shown below:-

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: <CustomHeaderClass />
  }
```

Comment: I also tried this but for iPhone x it is not working